# How to sync photos from iOS to MacBook just as songs sync from MacBook to iOS

Tags: itunes, photos

If I am at a camp site with no internet access, but with a wifi router, a macbook, and an iPhone, I can sync songs on iTunes from the macbook to the iPhone seamlessly. No need for cables, no need to go through Apple's servers.

How can I do the same with photos, but in the other direction? You're traveling, for instance, and you'd like to backup the photos on your phone to your macbook, wirelessly (wifi/bluetooth), automatically (just as with iTunes), and without going through iCloud. What is the recipe?

Comment: This is odd they should sync to your photos app.  Are you logged into the same Apple ID on both the iPhone and iOS? In iPhone Settings is  Settings>Photos>iCloud Photo Library switched on?  In Mac Photos.app is Photos>Preferences>iCloud iPhone Library checked off? If you do not have enough space on iCloud you can try Photo Stream. You can check it off in iPhone: Settings>Photos>My Photo Stream and on Mac:  Photos>Preferences>My Photo Stream.  Photo stream "Automatically upload[s] new phones and send[s] them to all of your iCloud devices when connected to Wi-Fi." And there is no storage cap.

Comment: Ok thanks you. Will add the answer without the inconsistencies shortly.

Comment: The real problem here is Photos.app "updating" which is discussed over at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8128611

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so both solutions are great and I am also shock why isnt your photos syncing across device if they are both connected with the **same WiFi** and logged in with the **same iCloud account**

However, these are my two suggestions:

1. Update both your iPhone and Mac device to the latest software version. Check this site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264 on how to do that and how to turn on iCloud for photos
2. Read a little about AirDrop. AirDrop is powerful. I use it daily and it is my style of transferring things between my Apple products. Please check this site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144 on how to use it. It is easy and **VERY** fast to use. It is probably the most fastest way to solve your problem

   - I hope this will solve your problem. Have a nice day !

Comment: Although Airdrop is a great feature it is not automatic as requested.